# Did I just brick my Apple TV's internet capability?

Tags: network, xcode, appletv, developer-program

I tried to spoof my location with Xcode for my Apple TV 4, with a blank app. As soon I did this my network connection dropped and showed an internal IP from the Apple TV (and not WiFi option, only ethernet). So, I hard reset it via iTunes and it still only gives me the option ethernet (there is no option to connect via WiFi). Even when I plug the ethernet cable in it does not work and says 'no network connection found'. Also I am not able to set get connected via the option to set up the Apple TV with my iPhone?

Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this? Or did I totally brick my Apple TV?

Steps I already took:

1. Hard reset via an IPSW via iTunes.
2. Called Apple Care for help (they do not have a solution, I can go to
   genius bar to check it out: I'll but no free slots)
3. Restarted/reset router
4. Different lan-cable/try to get ethernet connection via my Mac
5. Settings back via Xcode, but it tells me I have to activate my Apple TV first (which I cannot do because I can't get internet to work)

Thanks in advance! Apple TV is on 10.0.1

Update 12 december: made an appointment with the genius bar for Wednesday.

Answer (score 1):

Do a clean install of tvOS 10 on your Apple TV

1. Download the tvOS 10 on [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com)
2. Once the download is complete, launch iTunes.
3. Now connect your Apple TV 4 unit to your computer using a USB-C to USB-A cable.
4. Assuming your Apple TV 4 is connected to your computer and powered on, you’ll see your device listed in iTunes in the top left hand corner. Click on it to select.
5. Click on the ‘Restore’ button while holding down the left ‘Option’ key. A new window will come into view asking you to select a firmware file.
6. Select the firmware file you downloaded in step 1 and you’re good to go.

The restoration process won’t take that long and iTunes will throw you a prompt when things are complete.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I already did, but did not work.

Comment: @Lencon be sure to edit your question to include actions you've already taken to resolve the problem.  This will prevent others from proposing solutions/answers you've already tried and wasting each of your time.  See [ask] for tips on asking good questions.

Comment: Good answer. It's a shame the OP hadn't explained they'd already tried it, but I'm sure it'll be useful for others.

Comment: before the hard reset, i suggest to stop the apple tv 15 minutes, and even disconnect the power plug. sometime wifi components fall in security mode, to prevent them from burning. after 15 minutes and less heat they sometime come back to life. the danger of spoofing.

Comment: @monomeeth & fsb, thanks for ur advice, I'll edit my post and make it more clear that I already tried it. Maybe my formulation of 'hard reset via iTunes' was not specific enough.

Comment: It is really strange that a clean install or hard reset is not fixing the problem. Maybe spoof it back to it original setting (if that is possible)?

Comment: @pjtech yeah, I tried to do it in Xcode but tell me I first have to active it... And that is only possible via internet.